# Get list of secret key ids

Tags: gnupg

How can I easily get a list of secret key IDs available to the current GnuPG user?

I want a hypothetical command `gpg --foo` which I can use for:

```sh
keyids=$( ( gpg --foo ) )
for keyid in "${keyids[@]}" ; do …
```

What is the `gpg --foo` command that will just get me the key IDs for my secret keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It takes several seconds to complete, but this works:

```
gpg --list-secret-keys --with-colons \
    2> /dev/null \
    | grep '^sec:' | cut --delimiter ':' --fields 5
```

Thanks to @dirkt and @grawity for pieces of this answer.

Answer (score 3):

For version 2.1.15, the following works for me:

```
gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format short | grep sec | cut -d' ' -f 4
```

I'm not sure if the output format stayed identical among versions, so you may have to adapt the following commands if your version uses a differently formatted output.

Comment: If you want a format that stays identical, use `--with-colons`.

Comment: @grawity: I got curious and tried `--with-colons`, but it looks like you need to do extra mangling for the short form, and I don't know enough to do this reliably - always pick the last 8 chars?

Answer (score 3):

My option is using awk:

```
gpg --list-secret-keys --with-colons | awk -F: '$1 == "sec" {print $5}'
```